# Is there an alternative to require() in Node.JS? A "soft require" which tries to find a file but doesn't error if it isn't there

Tags: node.js, config, require

I'm loading a `config.json` file using `require('./config.json')` but I don't want to require a config file if they want to pass command line arguments instead, or just use the defaults.  Is there any way to try to load a JSON file this way but not spit out an error if it can't be found?

Comment: You could test for the file first

Comment: If it is just a JSON, load it manually using `fs`. There you can check, if the file actually exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general modules, you can check for existence before trying to load. In the following `path` is whatever path you want to load and `process()` is a function performing whatever processing you'd like on your module:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.exists(path, function (exists) {
    if (exists) {
        var foo = require(path);
        process(foo);
    }
    else {
        // Whatever needs to be done if it does not exist.
    }
});
```

And remember that `path` above must be an *actual path*, and not a module name to be later resolved by Node as a path.

For a JSON file specifically, with `path` and `process` having the same meanings as above:

```
fs.readFile(path, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // Whatever you must do if the file cannot be read.
        return;
    }

    var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
    process(parsed);    
});
```

You can also use `try... catch` but keep in mind that v8 won't optimize functions that have `try... catch` in them. With `path` and `process` meaning the same as above:

```
try {
    var foo = require(path);
    process(foo);
}
catch (e) {
    if (e.code !== "MODULE_NOT_FOUND")
        throw e; // Other problem, rethrow.
    // Do what you need if the module does not exist.      
}
```

Comment: Good solution! Too bad Node doesn't have an `include()` statement like PHP - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php